# Understanding assembly code for LED blink with ATmega328P

Tags: avr, assembly, atmega328p

I wrote the following program to turn an LED on and off at 1-second intervals:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0b00100000;
    for (;;) {
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried disassembling the binary file of this code using the `avr-objdump` of which the output is:

```
00000080 <main>:
  80:   80 e2           ldi r24, 0x20   ; 32
  82:   84 b9           out 0x04, r24   ; 4

00000084 <.L2>:
  84:   85 b9           out 0x05, r24   ; 5
  86:   2f ef           ldi r18, 0xFF   ; 255
  88:   33 ed           ldi r19, 0xD3   ; 211
  8a:   90 e3           ldi r25, 0x30   ; 48

0000008c <.L1^B1>:
  8c:   21 50           subi    r18, 0x01   ; 1
  8e:   30 40           sbci    r19, 0x00   ; 0
  90:   90 40           sbci    r25, 0x00   ; 0
  92:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x8c <.L1^B1>
  94:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0x96 <L0^A>

00000096 <L0^A>:
  96:   00 00           nop
  98:   15 b8           out 0x05, r1    ; 5
  9a:   2f ef           ldi r18, 0xFF   ; 255
  9c:   33 ed           ldi r19, 0xD3   ; 211
  9e:   90 e3           ldi r25, 0x30   ; 48

000000a0 <.L1^B2>:
  a0:   21 50           subi    r18, 0x01   ; 1
  a2:   30 40           sbci    r19, 0x00   ; 0
  a4:   90 40           sbci    r25, 0x00   ; 0
  a6:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0xa0 <.L1^B2>
  a8:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0xaa <L0^A>

000000aa <L0^A>:
  aa:   00 00           nop
  ac:   eb cf           rjmp    .-42        ; 0x84 <.L2>

000000ae <_exit>:
  ae:   f8 94           cli

000000b0 <__stop_program>:
  b0:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xb0 <__stop_program>
```

My understanding of the above assembly code is:

- the two lines under `00000080 <main>:` sets the data direction of PB5 to output.
- `00000084 <.L2>:` section turns the LED on.
- `0000008c <.L1^B1>:` waits for 1 second (first 4 lines) which then jumps to `00000096 <L0^A>:`
- `00000096 <L0^A>:` turns the LED off by writing the contents of `r1` (which is currently 0s) to PB5
- then `000000a0 <.L1^B2>:` waits for 1 second and jumps to `000000aa <L0^A>:`
- `000000aa <L0^A>:` spends one clock cycle and jumps to `00000084 <.L2>:` which turns the LED on. So on and so forth.

Questions:

1. Is my understanding of the assembly code correct?
2. What is the purpose of a `nop` sometimes as the first instruction?

Comment: Have you checked the data sheets to see if R24 is a data direction register?

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to learn assembly, I don't recommend this method. Compilers often produce code that is harder to understand than assembly code generated by humans.

Comment: @Andyaka I checked the datasheet and thought that 0x04 is the data direction register. I thought that I'm writing the contents of r24 to 0x04, I may be wrong...

Comment: @kovac you are right: `r24` is often used as a temporary register.  Data direction register B is at IO address 4, ie, when using `OUT`.  (And also at memory address 0x24, for when using ST.)  It's a pecularity of this CPU that some registers appear in both IO and memory address spaces, but with different addresses.

Comment: Take a look here https://godbolt.org/z/9jTd7sdnj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In general, yes, but disassembling the raw binary may not be very fruitful, as you could just look at the compiler output listing which includes the C source code and generated assembly opcodes.
2. You ask for 1000 millisecond delay, which is done by looping 3199999 times. As the loop will be a few clock cycles less than 1000 milliseconds, it adds extra useless RJMP and NOP opcodes to waste a few clock cycles to end up closer to 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: For 1., how do I get this?

Comment: Most C compilers support `-S` for making the assmbler file filename.s from filename.c.  If you're using the avr toolset, `avr-gcc -S -Os -mmcu=atmega328 -c filename.c` is likely to give you useful output.   Also look at assembler listing output: `avr-as -mmcu=atmega328 -o filename.o -a=filename.lst filename.s`